# Hover Item with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Is there a way to hover an element using javascript?
I don't want to create another class, I just want to cause element to hover with javascript when my mouse pointer is not over that element.

For example I have 5 elements with the same class and I want to call hover on all of them when one of them is actually hovered.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "hover the item"? Make it look different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean the pseudo class `:hover` that you've associated with a link (for example). As you hover over that link, you want to invoke all other link's `:hover` styles.

Unfortunately, you can not invoke the `:hover` styles from jQuery, that requires that you actually move your mouse pointer over that element. You have to use classes and utilize jQuery's hover event.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by addressing all of the items in your collection at the same time in your hover event handlers

```
var items = $(".some-class-applied-to-many-different-items");
items.hover(function() {
        // Mouseover state
        items.addClass("blah"); // <- for example
    },
    function() {
        // Mouseout state
        items.removeClass("blah");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you've added a `hover` event using jQuery, and you'd like to trigger that event manually regardless of the mouse.

If I understood correctly, you want to call the [`mouseenter`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter#fn) to trigger the `mouseenter` event.

If I've understood incorrectly, and you actually have a `:hover` CSS rule which you'd like to trigger using Javascript, that's not possible.
Instead, you should add a class name to the rule (eg, `something:hover, something.FakeHover { ... }`), and add that class name using jQuery.  (eg, `$(...).addClass('FakeHover')`).

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, [the `trigger` function](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger#eventdata) allows you to trigger events (including`mouseover`, I believe) on elements.

In straight JavaScript, if you’ve assigned a function to an element’s event handler, you can of course call that whenever you want. E.g.

```
function mouseoverHandler() {
    // Do something
}

// Assign function to element’s event handler
document.getElementById('link1').onmouseover = mouseoverHandler

// Call that function
document.getElementById('link1').onmouseover();
```

Comment: You don't even need `trigger`, calling the event without callback function works as well, for example `$('#foo').click();` will fire `#foo`'s click event.

Comment: Right, but I don’t think that works for `mouseover`. According to [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events), `mouseover()` just lets you bind a function to an element’s mouseover event. It doesn’t let you trigger the event.

Comment: Even though the documentation doesn't mention it, it does work for `mouseover`.  I check the source.

Comment: trigger.("mouseover") does not work to change the CSS class, but it does work to initiate a jquery function for "mouseover". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover