# Generating a click event in a WebView

Tags: objective-c, dom, webkit, dom-events

I am trying to generate a click event on a particular DOMNode via a menu item on the Mac. I thought this would be pretty simple however, I have seemed to hit a roadblock and not sure where I went wrong.

```
DOMDocument* domDocument=[webView mainFrameDocument];

DOMEvent* event = [domDocument createEvent:@"HTMLEvents"];
[event initEvent:@"click" canBubbleArg:YES cancelableArg:NO];

[[[domDocument getElementsByClassName:@"logout clickable"] item:0] dispatchEvent:event];
```

DOMEvent seems to be lacking a few methods that I had expected to see. I was expecting to have to code like this.

```
DOMEvent* event = [domDocument createEvent:@"MouseEvents"];
[event initMouseEvent:@"click" canBubbleArg:YES cancelableArg:NO];
```

However, mouse events don't seem to be available. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can call through to a JS-Script

Comment: I would prefer to do it all in Obj-C

Comment: @CodaFi In some cases using JS won't actually work, such as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/trigger-css-hover-with-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach has worked for me in the past:

```
DOMElement *el = // find element somehow
DOMDocument *doc = [el ownerDocument];
DOMAbstractView *window = [doc defaultView];
DOMUIEvent *evt = (DOMUIEvent *)[doc createEvent:@"UIEvents"];
[evt initUIEvent:@"click" canBubble:YES cancelable:YES view:window detail:1];
[el dispatchEvent:evt];
```

I believe that is all standard DOM2 Events module APIs. I think I found this solution from looking at the JavaScript on this [MozDev `createEvent` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createEvent).

---

Also note the `-[DOMHTMLElement click]` method in WebKit's *DOMHTMLElement.h* which is marked as `AVAILABLE_AFTER_WEBKIT_VERSION_5_1`.

---

Finally, I have occasionally had to resort to something hackier to fully simulate a user "mouse click" and all the DOM events that usually accompany it. I would only try this if nothing else above works (this is complex, ugly and brittle):

```
WebView *webView = // get web view
DOMElement *el = // find element somehow
id relatedTarget = [(DOMHTMLDocument *)[el ownerDocument] body];

[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"mouseover" clickCount:0 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:relatedTarget webView:webView];
[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"mousemove" clickCount:0 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:nil webView:webView];
[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"mousedown" clickCount:1 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:nil webView:webView];
[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"click" clickCount:1 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:nil webView:webView];
[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"mouseup" clickCount:1 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:nil webView:webView];
[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"mousemove" clickCount:0 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:nil webView:webView];
[el dispatchMouseEventType:@"mouseout" clickCount:0 ctrlKey:NO altKey:NO shiftKey:NO metaKey:NO button:0 relatedTarget:relatedTarget webView:webView];
```

---

I have a lot of this code in my open source project [TDAppKit on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/tdappkit/source/browse/trunk/src/DOMElement%2BTDAdditions.m).

Comment: That last approach looks great. But how do you execute objective C code on these events ? For example, I want to open another window controller when the user clicks on a web view .

Comment: That's a different question. Present your question in the form of a new question with the appropriate tags. And upvote this answer if it has been useful to you.