# how to loop a hover though elements of a class at some interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, foreach

I want to animate a hover over some elements after some period, but can't seem to get it right.

Here's what i tried.

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function setHover() {
        $('.header_Icons_Main').each(function(i, obj) {
            $(this).mouseenter()
        });
    }
    setInterval(setHover, 1000);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the function that it is trying to trigger?

Comment: If you are trying to trigger a CSS `:hover`, you can't. You'll need to toggle a class.

Comment: Your code works...http://jsfiddle.net/CTZuv/ unless you are doing something with CSS :hover....

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to trigger a CSS hover (styles defined by something like `.header_Icons_Main:hover`), unfortunately it looks like you can't do this with JavaScript. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4347249/3508398) for more info.

You can, however, define a class that adds your desired hover styles and add/remove this class via JS.

```
function setHover() {
    $('.header_Icons_Main').addClass('hover');
}
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mj9Y/).

**Edit**: After reading your updated intention to sequentially trigger hover states on each item, I've updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9mj9Y/6/).

Comment: @user3109875 Did the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mj9Y/6/) in this answer solve your problem?