# Magento try to trigger a mouseover effect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I'm running puro icotheme for Magento and I would really love to trigger the cart preview (available on mouseover on the header) right after a customer click add to cart on the product page..
This is my code but the console gives the Unexpected Token error

`<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to cart');?>"`
`data-button="<i class='fs1' aria-hidden='true' data-icon=''></i><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span>" class="btn-cart"`
`onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); document.getElementsByClassName("icon-cart-header")[1].click()">`

I tried both onmouseover() and click()...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Have you tried `trigger()` function ? http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Tells me trigger is not a function. document.getElementsByClassName("icon-cart-header").trigger( "click" );

Comment: It's a jquery function so you can use it like this : `$('.icon-cart-header').trigger("click");`
Also make sure to include jQuery library

Comment: I'm using like this  jQuery(".cart-container")[1].trigger("click"); but keep saying is not a function...

Comment: What is this `[1]` before the trigger event ? Can you do a small JSFiddle with the relevant part of the code so we can have a view of this please ?

Comment: I added [1] to select one element of the returned array.

Comment: here is the code [link] https://jsfiddle.net/kfejg4fj/

Comment: The desired outcome is to display the cart preview after adding the item starting from one of any product pages like this one https://www.capolavori.com/euro/lamanupina-avorio-accessories-bags-shoulder-bags-0001200017.html

Comment: It's more like a popup as I see it. Maybe check about popup plugin with jQuery.

Comment: for what I see the pop up is class= cart-wrapper" and I am trying to show it from chrome console. I can show it changing opacity and visibility but what I want is to show it for a while and then hide it again...

Comment: Oh ok, so in that case, check about `setTimeout()` function :)

Comment: Tried this https://jsfiddle.net/r2cr6j7c/, but seems it's ignoring the code.... Sorry I'm being dumb but I am new both to javascript and magento :-(

Comment: You have to put HTML code as well to make it works in the JSFiddle. Try to debug with the browser inspector and the javascript console if there are errors, it will output something in there.

Comment: Ok I coded this function [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/6yvpLrLm/) and it works but it seems that override the normal behaviour on mouseover. I saw that now the effect is performed through css :hov transition. This is why probably I cannot use .show() and .hide(). How can I trigger :hov css from another button then?

Comment: showshopping cart.. you can't see it? I'm calling it from the onclick and it actually works but then the cart-wrapper :hover CSS seems overridden and it does not work anymore on the page

Comment: In your JSFiddle, there's only a JS function with no html / css code at all. I can't help you without a complete example of the issue sorry :/

Comment: I think that my problem is the same of this case :-( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/trigger-css-hover-with-js

Comment: Why not play with class like it said in this post ? Do a `.hover` class which contain the same state as `:hover` and add it with your JS function, no ?

Comment: Trying to do it :-) But I'm very new to everything so very simple things seem very hard to me

Comment: After I created the class I just have to use onmouseover function?

Comment: I know a very simple way to do that with jQuery, here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/6yvpLrLm/1/ 
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! And what if I want to trigger the same effect but from a button, after an onclick event?

Comment: I've made an answer to make it easier to find for people ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger a css `:hover` with a class, you can do it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/6yvpLrLm/1/) :

```
$("a").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

If you want to trigger the same effect but from a `button` after a click event, you can do it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/6yvpLrLm/11/) :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Or [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/6yvpLrLm/12/) to toggle the class on the link from a button :

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("a").toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: Thank Vincent! This is great!!! I think we are nearly there but there is something I don't quite understand. In the CSS the :hover class is assigned like this .cart-container:hover .cart-wrapper { ...}. So is it possible to change style on a subclass using :hover? In this case which Jquery class I have to create? Cart-container.hover or cart-container.cart-wrapper.hover...

Comment: If `.cart-container` is a parent of `.cart-wrapper`, it is possible that way : https://jsfiddle.net/6yvpLrLm/22/ 
In that case, you need to create the class which simulate the `:hover` on the element. The best way now for you is to try to play with this and understand how it works ;) 
I'm here if you need further information, don't forget to validate the subject if my answer is ok for you :)