# Is there any way to simulate onmouseover in Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, firefox, onmouseover, firefox-developer-tools

I know that Firefox has a way to simulate hover, active and focus filters.

[image]

**Is there any way to simulate `onmouseover` elevation?**

I want to simulate this in two elements together, is this possible?

I didn't find any extension for this purpose. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use dispatch to send / fire an event for an element: `element.dispatchEvent(event);`. The [support may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/) on different browsers and versions; [my demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8kzj40s/31/) worked on chrome 65.

This is the demo

```js
function simulateMouseOver() {  
  var item2 = document.querySelectorAll("ul li")[1];
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', 
           {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true});
      
  var cancelled = !item2.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
        // a handler called preventDefault.
        
  } else {
        // none of the handlers called preventDefault.

  }
}

var menu =  document.getElementById("menu");
menu.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){   
   event.target.style.backgroundColor = "lime";
   setTimeout(function() { 
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
   }, 800);
}, false);
```

```css
ul {background-color: lightgray}
```

```html
<h3>Sample to fire onmouseover using a script</h3>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="simulateMouseOver()">simulate onMouseOver item two</button>
```

The html

```html
<h3>Sample to fire onmouseover using a script</h3>
<ul id="menu">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="simulateMouseOver()">simulate onMouseOver</button>
```

Below an onmouseover-event is set for `<ul id=menu>`. As soon as the mouse is moved over ul or any node inside ul:

```js
var menu =  document.getElementById("menu");
menu.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){   
     event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
     setTimeout(function() {
          event.target.style.backgroundColor = "";
     }, 500);
}, false)();
```

To  raise the onmouseover-event from inside a script you

1. first have to create the correct event
2. an then fire / dispatch this event to the target-element

See this code

```js
function simulateMouseOver() {

  var item2 = document.querySelectorAll("ul li")[1];
  var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', 
           {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true});      
  var cancelled = !item2.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
        // a handler called preventDefault.
        
  } else {
        // none of the handlers called preventDefault.

  }
}
```

You can find out more at

- [MDN dispatch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)
- [MDN event mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)

The [question simulate a mouse click from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157929/) or [Trigger events in javascript from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/) may be of use regarding the support in older browsers.

Comment: Additional links [Trigger css hover with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/)  or [simulate css hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/)

Comment: This answer helped me achieve the forced mouseover event firing I was looking for in my Angular app. This worked for me: `$('TARGET_SELECTOR').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseover', {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));` in Chrome v71.0.3578.80.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, as it is selected in your image you can use the `dispatchEvent` method only you must previously create the event in the chrome console and execute it.

1. pre-create  *:hover*  event

```js
var event = new MouseEvent("mouseover");
```

2. You send the event to the DOM element where `$0` is the element that you have selected in the debugger of your browser (in your case a div with the class facebox)

```js
$0.dispatchEvent(event)
```