# How to enable mouseenter/ mouseover state of an element for debugging purpose using developer tools?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

Is there anything similar to activating the hover state (CSS) for activating javascript events?

[image]

So I'm using Angular Materials tooltip. Everything works fine. I need to style the tooltip as per the theme but can't inspect the element as it's only visible when the mouse moves over the element.

https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples#tooltip-custom-class
The custom class works and I can change the color. I'd like to change the width and other CSS properties but I can't inspect the element to check what styles are getting applied by default.

So the main question is:
**Is there anything similar to activating the hover state (CSS) for activating javascript events (mouseover/mouseenter)?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to simulate onmouseover in Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231201/is-there-any-way-to-simulate-onmouseover-in-developer-tools)

Comment: Not really. It's a hacky way to go about it. I was inquiring if there was a way to directly do it from the dev tools rather than writing javascript in the console. @FabianS.

Comment: Fabian's answer is the best way to accomplish this goal. Use the `.dispatchEvent` method with `new Event("mouseover")` for testing outside something like puppeteer

Answer (score 5):

A cool trick to capture `mouseenter:mouseleave` events:

1. Open the console (in the browser)then enter:

`setTimeout(() => {debugger;}, 5000)`

press enter and hover above the item after the time 5s you can debug/ style the element.

2. Open source tab in the browser then press F8

Comment: This is an amazing idea! Works for a lot of things. Far better than trying to put breakpoints in the right places or firing events manually.