# Trying to make a different column highlight when mousing over a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on creating a recipe display for my homepage. When you hover over the roasted pepper and artichoke tapenade box, i want the image to the left of it to trigger its mouseover event. I also want to do the reverse. So if you hover over the image left of the roasted pepper box, the text on the right should trigger its mouseover event. **Also, the recipe boxes only show if the screen size is greater than 768px.** I am hiding this on mobile. Hoping someone can help. I have been trying many different techniques with no success.  I am not sure how to do this correctly. Thanks!

```js
$('.recipeHighlight').hover(
   function(){ $(this).addClass('recipeOverlayStyle') }, 
   function(){ $(this).removeClass('recipeOverlayStyle') }
)
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="https://www.cento.com/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://www.cento.com/css/image-effects.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Featured Recipes Row -->
<div class="visible-lg visible-md"> 
<section id="cento-white-background-half-padding-background" data-speed="4" data-type="background">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">  
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <img class="img-responsive recipeContainerImg" src="images/logos/cento_logo.png" width="200px" alt="Cento Fine Foods"> 
    <h1 class="center">RECIPES FROM OUR KITCHEN</h1>
    <br>
   </div> 
  </div>
  <!-- Recipe Row #1 Start --> 
        <div class="row rowBackground"> 
         <div onclick="void(0)" class="col-md-3 col-img">
              <div class="hovereffect"> 
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.cento.com/images/recipes/appetizers/roasted-pepper-artichoke-tapenade.jpg" alt="Roasted Pepper and Artichoke Tapenade">
                    <div class="overlay">
               <a class="info" href="https://www.cento.com/recipes/appetizers/roasted-pepper-artichoke-tapenade.php">View Recipe</a>
           </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-img recipeBG recipeHighlight">
             <h1>Roasted Pepper & Artichoke Tapenade</h1>  
   </div>
   <div onclick="void(0)" class="col-md-3 col-img">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.cento.com/images/recipes/appetizers/olive_tapenada.jpg" alt="Olive Tapenade">
                    <div class="overlay">
               <a class="info" href="recipes/appetizers/olive_tapenada.php">View Recipe</a>
           </div> 
                </div>  
            </div> 
   <div class="col-md-3 col-img recipeBG recipeHighlight">
             <h1>Olive<br>Tapenade</h1>  
   </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
</section>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the hover effects for your images are being handled completely by your CSS, it's not possible to kick off that effect in jQuery/JavaScript. Having said that, if you change the way you approach it just a little, you can reuse most of your code.

To do this, you need to initiate the hover effect with jQuery. The easiest way to do this is to add/remove a CSS class that takes you to your hovered state. Once you've got the desired hover effect being handled by jQuery, simply modify your existing `hover()` event handler to get the previous div and add/remove your hover state class.

Here's a quick and dirty example to get you started (missing the overlay):

```js
$('.recipeHighlight').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).prev("div").find("img").addClass("hoverExample");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).prev("div").find("img").removeClass("hoverExample");
  }
);
```

```css
.hoverExample {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="https://www.cento.com/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://www.cento.com/css/image-effects.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="visible-lg visible-md">
  <section id="cento-white-background-half-padding-background" data-speed="4" data-type="background">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img class="img-responsive recipeContainerImg" src="images/logos/cento_logo.png" width="200px" alt="Cento Fine Foods">
          <h1 class="center">RECIPES FROM OUR KITCHEN</h1>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Recipe Row #1 Start -->
      <div class="row rowBackground">
        <div onclick="void(0)" class="col-md-3 col-img">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.cento.com/images/recipes/appetizers/roasted-pepper-artichoke-tapenade.jpg" alt="Roasted Pepper and Artichoke Tapenade">
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="https://www.cento.com/recipes/appetizers/roasted-pepper-artichoke-tapenade.php">View Recipe</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-img recipeBG recipeHighlight">
          <h1>Roasted Pepper & Artichoke Tapenade</h1>
        </div>
        <div onclick="void(0)" class="col-md-3 col-img">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.cento.com/images/recipes/appetizers/olive_tapenada.jpg" alt="Olive Tapenade">
            <div class="overlay">
              <a class="info" href="recipes/appetizers/olive_tapenada.php">View Recipe</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-img recipeBG recipeHighlight">
          <h1>Olive<br>Tapenade</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
  </section>
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

See [Trigger css hover with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/trigger-css-hover-with-js) for additional information.