# Add :hover pseudo-class via js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<p class="text">Some text</p>

<style>
.text:hover{
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

How can I trigger hover event that text becomes red via js or jquery? I need a solution without adding a new css class.

Comment: `I need a solution without adding a new css class.` It's not possible then. You cannot invoke the CSS `:hover` selector from JS. See this specific answer in the duplicate I marked for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244507/519413

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Very bad to hear it, but now at least I know that it is impossible and will be looking for other ways

Comment: Toggling a class is the simplest workaround. Is there a specific reason you cannot just do that?

Comment: There are a lot of CSS rules I need to change. Plus I use Foundation and I will need to change sources/or rewrite rules in my file as well and I don't want to do that. Also, I will need to add this new class to all js functions which handle hover. So this approach add a lot of work, but as I see I don't have another way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `hover()` function of JQuery with syntax `hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` as you cannot manipulate `:hover` from JQuery.

```js
$('.text').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'black');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">Some text</p>
```

Comment: In the question: `I need a solution without adding a new css class.`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan corrected.

Comment: True. I suppose in the loosest sense it works, but I think the OP is more asking 'how can I trigger the CSS :hover selector from JS'.

Comment: Yeap. I need to trigger :hover but not handle. But still, thank you for try.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('color','red');
    },function(){
        $(this).css('color','initial');
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.text').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('color','red');
 },function(){
  $(this).css('color','initial');
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">Some text</p>
```

Comment: Thank but it is not what I need. Check this comment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923177/add-hover-pseudo-class-via-js-jquery/50923314#comment88845775_50923243

Comment: @DmytroHuz, you can't do it.

Comment: yeap already saw in duplicate topic. So trying to find another solution now.

Comment: @DmytroHuz,good luck.

Comment: Thank you, man! =)