# Trigger the css:hover event with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `<div class="animate">` and in css:

```
div.animate:hover{
//do stuff
}
```

But would also like to invoke this via javascript.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228376/trigger-onmouseover-event-programatically-in-javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger css hover with JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/trigger-css-hover-with-js)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hover Item with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983169/hover-item-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it this way, I suggest you just add a class to the other  tag. In jQuery it would be:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('.trigger-animate').hover(function(){
        $('.animate').addClass('hover');
    });
}
```

I'd recommend using this method, because it handles both onMouseOver and onMouseOut (this way you can also remove the class when your mouse leaves $('.trigger-animate') if you so desired using this syntax:

```
.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
 checking out the documentation
```

Comment: I'm new to jQuery, would this go in the "onMouseOver" ? If not, where would I put this code

Comment: Put it in  $(window).load --------
.hover is a replacement for onMouseOver, so you don't even need it!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still lost. Where do I put the .hover(...) in your second code snippet

Comment: The second snippet is just just the full syntactical documentation for the first. All you would need is the first one, and you could add a second function using the syntax of the second to handle when the mouse moves out. Hope that clears things up a bit.

Comment: is there no way to do this with vanilla JS?

Answer (score 6):

As described in [Trigger css hover with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347116/trigger-css-hover-with-js) this is not possible as-is (if you want it as described exactly at the time of the creation of this answer).

But the main goal is achievable by:

1. Setting a class `hover` (or whatever name) as well as the selector `:hover` in the CSS.
2. Calling `.addClass("hover")` to trigger CSS, and `.trigger("hover")` or `.trigger("mouseenter")` to trigger the JS.
3. Ensuring the `mouseleave` handler. or 2nd `.hover()` handler, clears the `hover` class if present.